# How would I go about graphing $2x+3 > x^2 + y^2$?

Tags: circles, graphing-functions

How would I go about graphing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. One may rewrite
$$
x^2+y^2<2x+3
$$as
$$
(x^2-2x+1)+y^2-1<3
$$or
$$
(x-1)^2+y^2<4.
$$

Answer (score 3):

The inequality is $(x-1)^{2}+y^{2} <4$. This is simply the set of points inside the circle of radius $2$ centered at $(1,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
$$4> (x^2-2x+1)+y^2 \,.$$